# What design pattern should I use to update values on an object of type T

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the following scenario and I'm trying to figure out what design pattern to place in the for loop.

The query will only ever return Bananas or Apples. Never a mix of bananas and apples. I know ahead of time when calling DoStuff, whether Bananas or Apples will be returned because I can control the query.

I've been trying an approach of passing through an interface as a second parameter to DoStuff that would either set the length of banana or diameter of apple.

Any suggestions as how I could achieve this? I need DoStuff to be re-usable.

```
    public class BaseClass
    {

    }

    public class Apple : BaseClass
    {
        public int Diameter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Banana : BaseClass
    {
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }

    public void DoStuff(Query query)
    {
        // The query only ever returns bananas OR Apples. Never both.
        var items = repository.GetItems<BaseClass>(query);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // Code to run some arbitrary calculation then set Length if Banana
            // Code to run some arbitrary calculation then set Diameter if Apple
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should it set the diameter if Apples?  The way your code is currently written, I don't see a direct way to do the two -- they have different properties.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I've updated the code to reflect that

Comment: Have you checked ORM Frameworks like EF, NHibernate which simplifies db part in a good extent. DBContext, ObjectContext gives you many advantages other than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why have a base class if no derived class shares any behaviour or data?  You should look into Liskov Substitution principle (LSP).  LSP basically says that correct systems adhere to strong behavioural subtyping and that in a polymorphic scenario when one type is substituted for another it will not violate correctness, etc.

You're clearly violating this principle by having two subclasses with nothing real in common.  I would suggest you look at a different way of approaching this and provide more detail on what you want to accomplish so someone might be able to help you accomplish what you need.

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, here's something I would suggest:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class Apple : BaseClass
{
    public int Diameter { get; set; }
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something specific for Apple
    }
}
//...
public void DoStuff(Query query)
{
    // The query only ever returns bananas OR Apples. Never both.
    var items = repository.GetItems<BaseClass>(query);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        item.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry:
The classes do share commonality, I just omitted that information to make it more concise.

I've also inherited this class architecture from a third party API.

Comment: Okay, the rest about abstract class and overrides should suit your needs.  If you're deriving from a 3rd party class, just make that abstract and derive your Apple and Banana classes from *your* abstract class.

Comment: Very well answered and thanks for helping de-fog my brain. In order to implement Liskovs on their code i'd have to write a wrapper around each of their classes. *Sad face*

Comment: yes, unfortunately a "wrapper" is in order--but, would do what you want and probably gives you Open/Closed principle too.  i.e. your foreach would be closed to modification but open to extension because you could simply add another fruit and extend behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your DoStuff method like this

```
public void DoStuff(Query query)
{
    // The query only ever returns bananas OR Apples. Never both.
    var items = repository.GetItems<BaseClass>(query);

    foreach (var item in items.OfType<Banana>())
    {
        // Code to set Length if Banana
    }
}
```

but I do prefer the Liskov Substitution principle...

Answer (score -1):

I'd make `DoStuff` an abstract method in `BaseClass` and override it in `Apple` & `Banana`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    // Stuff common to Apples & Bananas here

    public abstract void DoStuff(Query query);

}

public class Apple : BaseClass
{
    public int Diameter { get; set; }

    public override DoStuff(Query query)
    {
        // Implementation for Apples
    }
}

public class Bananas : BaseClass
{
    public int length { get; set; }

    public override DoStuff(Query query)
    {
        // Implementation for Bananas
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't compile as posted and "DoSomething" eerily looks like you copied it from *somewhere*. :\